# Iterating Through API Call In Array (GAS/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm still very new to JS and GAS. I have an API call to get certain data from a gov.uk API system. I've got to the point where I can call one variable (in this case a VRM) and get certain parts of data that I need out of it but I would like to add another version where I can put a bulk list of VRMs in and get 1 part (a date) back out and add that date next to that VRM. I've tried adding a for loop within to loop the VRMs in an array and I've tried adding this code within a for loop too but with no success.

Here is my code (blanked keys and link out for obvious reasons); any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
function motapi(reg) {

 // Clear Sheet before running
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("regList");
  var clearPrevious = destSheet.getRange('B2:B').clearContent(); 
  var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();

  //call api
  var vrm = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1).getValue();
    var keyoptions = {
      method : "GET",
      headers : {
    "Accept": "application/json+v6",
    "x-api-key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      }
  };
  var url = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' + vrm;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, keyoptions);
  var prompt = vrm + " | API call complete";

 // Logger.log(response)

  //parse response
  // var json = JSON.parse(response);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  Logger.clear();
 // Logger.log(data);
  // log seperate parts of json parse

 // Logger.log(data[0]["motTests"]);
 Logger.log(data[0].motTests[0].expiryDate);

  var dataSet = data[0].motTests //[0].expiryDate;


 // Log expiry dates

  var rows = [],
    data;
  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[i];
    rows.push([data.expiryDate]); //your JSON entities here
  };

 // Logger.log(rows);

// return api call variables to function
  return {
      motdata: json,


};
}

function goodWay() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('regList');
var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
var searchRange = sheet.getRange(1,1, lastRow-1, lastColumn-1);
var motApi = motapi();

  // Get array of values in the search Range
  var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();
  Logger.log(rangeValues);
  // Loop through array and if condition met, add relevant
  // background color.
  for ( i = 0; i < lastColumn - 1; i++){
    for ( j = 0 ; j < lastRow - 1; j++){
      if(rangeValues[j][i] === "-"){
        sheet.getRange(j+1,i+2).push(motApi);
      }else if (rangeValues[j][i] === 0){
        sheet.getRange(j+2,i+2).setValue();
      }; 
    };
  };

}
```

Comment: Something like this maybe? https://pastebin.com/chTUgGKr

Comment: Please consider adding the code you attempted to run (the one with the for loop) and describing the exact issue you had with it, so we can better understand your situation and give you better support. Cheers

Comment: @ChrisG - thanks for the help, this line returns a Syntax error? "const rows = data.map(d => d.expiryDate);"

Comment: @carlesgg97 - I've edited with the code I tried to run the loop on as a seperate function, it returns one expiry date for the top row but doesn't paste it to the sheet (regList) and gets all rows into an array including the header.

Comment: I see, maybe arrow functions aren't supported. Replace `d => d.expiryDate` with `function(d) { return d.expiryDate; }`, same for the other two.

Comment: @ChrisG - Thanks for your help so far. That seems to have worked but the `return {rows};` doesn't seem to? what is the purpose of this bit? as I don't think GAS likes it returned that way?

Comment: @MarkGeorge GAS does not use the latest Javascript standards, so some of the 'modern' features don't work indeed. You will have to substitute `return {
    rows,
    resultRows,
    rfrAndCommentsRows
  };` for `return { "rows": rows, "resultRows": resultRows, "rfrAndCommentsRows": rfrAndCommentsRows }`

Comment: @MarkGeorge As you can see, the code you have to provide to GAS is slightly more verbose. I imagine that in the line 32 of the pastebin provided by Chris you will encounter a similar issue. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring. Note that doing `const {p, q} = o;` is the same as doing `const p = o.p; const q =  o.q;` (we must use the latter in GAS).

Comment: thanks @carlesgg97 - GAS is stuck in ES5 I believe, that now kicks out an error for the for loop **Missing ; after for-loop initialiser. (line 27)** I've changed `const { rows }; = getVRMData(row,1);` to `const { "rows" }; = getVRMData(row,1);` but get the same error, I've only ever used var before so the const and let is new to me in GAS, i've done a few lessons on codecademy to try and get myself versed in it but never done anything this in depth. just copying sheets and setting dates next to completed data cells and sending daily PDFs etc. really appreciate all the help so far.

Comment: @MarkGeorge I have adapted the pastebin code here: https://pastebin.com/Sd5pG1Sc

Comment: @carlesgg97 - Thanks, should there be another function to run the for loop in? as it's erroring when trying to redefine a const value.

Comment: @MarkGeorge I don't quite understand what you mean, but yes it is a good idea to wrap the "main" code inside of a function (as: https://pastebin.com/qFw6RigJ). If you get the const error again please provide the error description and line of code where it happens. Cheers

Comment: @carlesgg97 - I moved it into a function as you suggested and it's sorted it. Now just trying to work out an alternative to `data.map` as `map` is a TypeError on google. Tried `push` as i've used that in the original single call script to no avail.